# Consultas y subconsultas en una misma tabla sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subconsultas

Hola tengo la siguiente tabla en sql server:

```
id | monto | operacion | medioPago | fecha      | hora 
1    2000    Ventas      efectivo    20-11-2022   12:00:00
2    1000    Anulacion   efectivo    20-11-2022   12:00:00
```

Bueno lo que quiero hacer es obtener la **diferencia** del **monto** según el **medio de pago** dependiendo de la **operación**, he intentado hacer un subconsulta dentro una consulta sql pero no he llegado a la solución

He hecho esta consulta por el momento que devuelva la suma sin discriminar la operación, lo que quiero que pueda restar el monto según la operación del medio del pago

```
declare @fromDate datetime = '2022-11-20 00:00:00.000'
declare @toDate datetime = '2022-11-20 00:00:00.000'

select Fecha, sum(Monto)
from [MovimientoCaja] 
where MedioPago = 'Efectivo' and Fecha between @fromDate and @toDate group by Fecha
```

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer una suma condicional, y construir un multiplicador en función al Medio de pago, 1 para los que suman y -1 para los que restarían:

```
select Fecha, 
       sum(Monto * (CASE WHEN MedioPago IN ('Anulacion') THEN -1 ELSE 1 END))
       from [MovimientoCaja] 
       where MedioPago = 'Efectivo' 
             and Fecha between @fromDate 
             and @toDate 
       group by Fecha
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ya pude entender de como funciona, 10+